# How to show transparent image with instructions over my activity?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with some photos, and I'm using ViewPager for swiping those photos. How can I show some transparent image at the activity start, just to show some instructions for swipe and stuff, like ES File Explorer did it on the image below? I have and image, transparent like the one below. I want to show it on top of my first image, and the user can swipe it.

[image]

Here's my class:

```
public class Photo_gallery extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button save;
    Context mContext;

    final File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/Images/");
    boolean success = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mContext = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.photo_gallery);

        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        final ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                final String fname = "StyleMe-" + n + ".png";

                myDir.mkdirs();

                File image = new File(myDir, fname);

                int currentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(adapter.mImages[currentItem]);
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

                // Encode the file as a PNG image.
                FileOutputStream outStream;
                try {

                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
                    /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    success = true;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success at /sdcard/Pictures/SexyImages",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse
                        ("file://"
                                                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

            }
        });

    }

    public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        public int[] mImages = new int[] { 
            R.drawable.p1,
            R.drawable.p2,
            R.drawable.p3,
          .
          .
          .
            R.drawable.p108
        };


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
          return mImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
          return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
          Context context = Photo_gallery.this;
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
          int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
              R.dimen.padding_medium);
          imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
          imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
          ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
          return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
          ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
      }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably to use [the ShowcaseView library](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/showcase-view/) for this.

Comment: What is the minimum API for this?

Comment: @marjanbaz: Ask the author, as I have no idea. The author describes using NineOldAndroids, which suggests it has been backported to earlier than API Level 11, but that's all I know.